# How to retrieve ONLY changed values in a Datatable and Put them into a unique string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to create a query generator similar to the one that MS Access uses. I have a datable that is binded to a DataGridView. When the user activates the form, he or she can enter values into the DataGridView which are then reflected in the datatable. I want to retrieve those values from the datatable however there is a catch:

Each row creates its own 'AND' statements and when it moves to a new row it adds an 'OR'. For example:

```
XXX OR RRR |        |    CCC       |             |  DDD          |
-----------|--------|--------------|-------------|-------------- |
           |        |     BBB      |             |               |
```

So the end result to the user input of the following table should be:

> ((XXX OR RRR) AND CCC AND DDD) OR BBB

This is very similiar to the design views of queries in MS Access.

I have tried using the GetValues() method, however that does not seem to fire for some reason. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    // Build string and then run to test and have user scroll through data  'test' 'run' after they view save,          dynamic or showing up, character check
    private void auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DataTable changed = new DataTable();
        changed =  dt.GetChanges();

        where_Clause = "";
        row_Count = auto_GridView1.Rows.Count;  // SHould the datagridview or the data rows be counted
        column_count = auto_GridView1.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < row_Count; i++)  
        {  
            // where_Clause += (row_Count - 1) ? "AND" + auto_GridView1[i, j].ToString() : string.Empty;
            if (i > 0)
            {                    
                where_Clause = where_Clause + " OR";                
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < column_count; j++)
            {                   
                // Need to see if the Value of the cell changed. If so must validate
                where_Clause += (i < column_count - 1) ?  "AND" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() : string.Empty;   // USE DATA TABLE  
            }
        }
```

This loops through the entire table and essentially connects a whole bunch of 'AND' Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I looped through each cell with an input and converted that to a string simply put. I called to other functions to accomplish other goals.

```
private void auto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Build string and then run to test and have user scroll through data  'test' 'run' after they view save,          dynamic or showing up, character check
    {

        //DataTable changed = new DataTable();
        // changed =  dt.GetChanges();



        where_Clause = "((";
        row_Count = auto_GridView1.Rows.Count;                // SHould the datagridview or the data rows be counted
        column_count = auto_GridView1.Columns.Count;



        for (int i = 0; i < row_Count - 1; i++)     // Begins by selecting the row
        {

            char[] MyChar = { 'A', 'N', 'D', ' ' };   
             where_Clause = where_Clause.TrimEnd(MyChar);                // Trims in the loop however doesnt pick up the last AND Still leaves last one

            if (i > 0 )    // Adds the 'OR' after Row [0] b/c 'OR' isnt needed at row[0]
            {
              where_Clause = where_Clause + "  ) OR ( ";    

            }

            for (j = 0; j < column_count - 1; j++)     // Loops through all the columns in a given row 
            {


                if (dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() != "")        // Checks to see if there is a value in the box. If so it adds it to the Clause

                {
                     header = "";
                     string current_cell = "";


                    header = get_correct_header(j);  // Use j to get the header ]

                    current_cell = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString(); // gets the current selection

                    current_cell = insert_correctHeader(current_cell, header); // reads throught he string pickling up the necessary symbols and inserting in the correct header name 

                    where_Clause += (i < column_count - 1) ?   current_cell + " AND " : string.Empty;   // USE DATA TABLE


                }




            }


        }


        char[] Mychar2 = { 'A', 'N', 'D', ' ' };           // Trim again to get rid of that final AND 
        where_Clause = where_Clause.TrimEnd(Mychar2); 
        where_Clause = where_Clause + "))";





        MessageBox.Show(where_Clause);  // We have the where clause here must be tested to see if it works
```